# AutocompleteBox navigation on suggestion tap

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to do navigation on suggestion tap in my AutocompleteBox but it doesn't work with InvokeCommandAction, I'm trying to navigate in command, here is my code:

```
<toolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding A}" ValueMemberBinding="{Binding B}" Style="{StaticResource SearchStyle}">
    <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Test, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Main}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding B}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

Comment: show us the Test code for the command! If you debug, the Test command is triggered?

Comment: In that command I only display MessageBox for tests but it not trigger.

Comment: did it work for you the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
 <toolkit:AutoCompleteBox Name="XPTO">
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>
         <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
             <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Test, Mode=OneTime}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=XPTO, Path=SelectedItem}" />
         </i:EventTrigger>
     </i:Interaction.Triggers>
 </toolkit:AutoCompleteBox>
```

You can send as a parameter the autocompletebox SelectedItem. In your ViewModel you just have to have

```
 public RelayCommand<TYPEOFSELECTEDITEM> Test{ get; private set; }
```

And in the constructor of ViewModel something like:

```
 this.Test= new RelayCommand<TYPEOFSELECTEDITEM>(()=>MessageBox.Show("Hello world"));
```

if you are not using ViewModel then this goes to where you set your DataContext.
If you are using ViewModel, you should not call MessageBox.Show in there...but that's another story.

Regards,